# Bootstrap's navbar code not working for me

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap and was trying to create navbar but it didn't work. I wasn't even trying to add any item in it. I was only trying to put my company's/brand's name in it. I have bought an online course and there the teacher uses the same code and it works for him.

This is the code. Please help me through this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Navbar is cool!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#">Google</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the expected output? and what do you actually see from your code?

Comment: `navbar-header` is used in bootstrap 3, and not in version 4, please read the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Google</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to add one reference in Navbar  this will do::

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Google</a>
  </nav>
```

maybe this is the code you were looking for.
check :https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/frcvu2d8/